# VBA excel how to fix the code (exclude rows that are empty ) do not fill the background in a color

Tags: excel, for-loop, if-statement, vba

i have a code written in VBA that will check the date and base on the it will fill the background  with the appropriate color.

i have cells (A to G ).

i want to check if the column C  is empty i want to keep the row transparent

```
  If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) Then
         Range("A" & i & ":G" & i).Interior.Color = xlNone
```

the problem is that the code step into the if statment to check if empty ... then it step into the last if statement and fill all the empty rows with the specified color.

## CODE:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Long

For i = Range("C5000").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 'Range upto 5000, chnge this as per your requirment'

    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) Then
         Range("A" & i & ":G" & i).Interior.Color = xlNone

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) < 0 Then
             Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) = 0 Then
             Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) >= 1 And (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) <= 4 Then
              Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) >= 5 And (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) <= 10 Then
               Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbCyan

    Else
                Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

 End If

    ' your 2nd criteria to color the entire row if "G" is not empty
    If Trim(Range("G" & i).Value) <> "" Then
                       Range("A" & i & ":G" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 15


  ElseIf Trim(Range("G" & i).Value) = "" Then
                       Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 189, 189)
                       Range("D" & i & ":G" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 189, 189)

 End If

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code comments mention that "your 2nd criteria to color the entire row if "F" is not empty" but the code actually refers to column G. Is that intentional?

Comment: Do you mean if C is empty the row should be "transparent" irrespective of whether or not G is blank?

Comment: @SJR YESSSS  IT doesn't matter if other columns are empty or not

Comment: @Moacir  its a mistake in the comments thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, just an added an extra If clause to your second statement

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Long

For i = Range("C5000").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 'Range upto 5000, chnge this as per your requirment'
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) Then
        Range("A" & i & ":G" & i).Interior.Color = xlNone
    ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) < 0 Then
        Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen
    ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) = 0 Then
        Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) >= 1 And (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) <= 4 Then
        Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed
    ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) >= 5 And (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) <= 10 Then
        Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbCyan
    Else
        Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If

    ' your 2nd criteria to color the entire row if "G" is not empty
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) Then
        If Trim(Range("G" & i).Value) <> "" Then
            Range("A" & i & ":G" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        ElseIf Trim(Range("G" & i).Value) = "" Then
            Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 189, 189)
            Range("D" & i & ":G" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 189, 189)
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```